# How to run Synaptic with sudo privileges?

Tags: sudo, synaptic

How to launch a program with `sudo` privilege in Unity? I am using Ubuntu 11.04.

I used this command but it doesn't really work:

```
sudo synaptic
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is what you mean, but you can try `gksu synaptic`.

Comment: what i was asking was that if u do a sudo nautilus or sudo synaptic in the run command i.e. Alt-F2 nothing happens sinply because there's no prompt for password. Is der any way to circumvent this.... I will try your suggestion.... ty..

Comment: Note that there was a typo in the answer. It's called "gksu" or "gksudo" (same thing), not "gtksu".

Comment: Using `gksu synaptic` should solve you problem. It will display a graphical password-box.

Comment: @Fraekkert Synaptic actually spawns its own prompt - so that could be a red herring.

Comment: [ARTICLE gksu Removed From Ubuntu](https://itsfoss.com/gksu-replacement-ubuntu/)

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, use the terminal which you can - as i do - keep in the unity starter. I belive its a thing of taste whether you use gksu or the terminal.